# rails password recovery

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How can I add password recovery to [sample_app](https://github.com/railstutorial/sample_app) by Michael Hartl?

Maybe someone has already done it.

Answer (score 3):

Fellow Stackers: If you downvote someone's question it's only common courtesy to let them know why. It's not helpful to anyone to just see "-3" and not realize why.

Anton, your question is a bit too general for Stack Overflow. You should really ask for help with specific errors/problems. What you need is a full tutorial and that's not what Stack is for.

Luckily this kind of thing is easy to Google, for example "rails password recovery" will lead to a Railscast with nice basic example code: [Remember Me & Reset Password](http://railscasts.com/episodes/274-remember-me-reset-password). If you're new to Rails watching all the Railscasts is a great way to learn too.

You could also look at existing authentication gems like Devise on Github and see how they do it.

Comment: First part of your answer should really be a comment.

Comment: That's true Sergio, was being lazy and dumped it all into one text ;)